# Can I use virtual abstract methods to inherit an interfaced object?

Tags: delphi, inheritance, interface

I have an interface and a corresponding object behind it. For example...

```
  IMyInterface = interface
    function GetSomething: WideString;
    procedure SetSomething(const Value: WideString);
    property Something: WideString read GetSomething write SetSomething
  end;

  TMyObject = class(TInterfacedObject, IMyInterface)
  private
    function GetSomething: WideString;
    procedure SetSomething(const Value: WideString);
  public
    property Something: WideString read GetSomething write SetSomething
  end;
```

I use this interface to be able to interact with this object across a DLL.

Now I would like to inherit this object and override some of these methods...

```
  TMyOtherObject = class(TMyObject)
  private
    function GetSomething: WideString; override;
    procedure SetSomething(const Value: WideString); override;
```

Except I'd like to make the base fields virtual and abstract to basically force the child to inherit these...

```
  TMyObject = class(TInterfacedObject, IMyInterface)
  private
    function GetSomething: WideString; virtual; abstract;
    procedure SetSomething(const Value: WideString); virtual; abstract;
```

Can I do this and have the interface still work with these fields? And do I need to define it this way within the interface too? (I know of course all fields in an interface are already abstract)

Comment: Why not tried in compiler by yourself? (learning by doing) - Why would you expect this is not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can indeed do this. A virtual method, abstract or otherwise, can be used to meet an interface contract.

You cannot declare the interface methods to be `virtual` or `abstract`. That makes little sense anyway because `virtual` and `abstract` are properties of implementation rather than interface.

Finally, you don't need to declare the property again in the implementing object. Since I expect you'll only be referring to these objects via the interface, it makes little point repeating the property declaration.

Here's a simple program to prove the point:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

type
  IMyInterface = interface
    procedure Foo;
  end;

  TMyObject = class(TInterfacedObject, IMyInterface)
  private
    procedure Foo; virtual; abstract;
  end;

  TMyOtherObject = class(TMyObject)
  private
    procedure Foo; override;
  end;

procedure TMyOtherObject.Foo;
begin
  Writeln(ClassName);
end;

var
  Intf: IMyInterface;

begin
  Intf := TMyOtherObject.Create;
  Intf.Foo;
  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: So just declare it like normal in the interface, don't even implement it in the base interfaced object, and leave it up to the derived objects to implement it?

Comment: You only need to declare the property in the interface. That's all. That's because you'll only ever access the object via the interface.

Comment: Makes sense, any inheritance of this base object would need to override it anyway. But it's still good to know I can use virtual abstract methods in an interfaced object.

Comment: I'm slapping myself in the face for not getting to know interfaces much earlier...